# How can I call a function from Chrome console?

Tags: reactjs

I have react component:

```
const App = ()=> {
function ASD() {
alert("ASD");}}
```

I want in Chrome console type ASD(); and get the alert.

Answer (score 2):

Just add it to the global `window` object.

```js
function ASD() {
  alert('ASD');
}
window.ASD = ASD;

const App = () => {};
```

console

```js
ASD(); // or
window.ASD();
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming - your code might be looking like following, since the one OP has provided, is not a valid react-component -

```
const App = ()=> {
   function ASD() {
      alert("ASD");
   }
   window.ASD = ASD; // add this to read `ASD` from console by using "window.global"
   return null; // this was at-least missing for the App to be a valid functional component
}
```

OP wants to call `ASD` from `console`(developer-console in Chrome). That could be done by attaching the function to the `window` global variable - like done in the above code.